# How to implement the search in the DataTable (Web Application Development Tutorial)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, abp

I'm absolutely new to the ABP-Framework. I've followed the "Web Application Development Tutorial".
Now I want to use the search in the DataTable.
In the file "Index.js" I've set the "search" to "true" but nothings happens.

```
var dataTable = $('#WordsTable').DataTable(
   abp.libs.datatables.normalizeConfiguration({
   serverSide: true,
   paging: true,
   order: [[1, "asc"]],
   searching: true,
   scrollX: true,
   ...
```

How can the search be implemented?
Regards, Tom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set `searching:true` for your datatable it only searches through current page values by row. (https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching)

So, if you want to search records according to your all records, you need to add a **search input** on your **.cshtml** file and get the value of that search input and pass this value to the **GetList** method(of course you need to override the GetList method from YourAppService as well).

**Steps:**

- Create a new DTO

MySearchFilterDto.cs -> (under ApplicationContracts)

```cs
public class MySearchFilterDto : PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto
{
   public string Filter { get; set; }
}
```

- Change the `IBookAppService` and `BookAppService`

IBookAppService.cs

```cs
public interface IBookAppService :
        ICrudAppService< 
            BookDto, 
            Guid, 
            MySearchFilterDto, //Used for paging/sorting + filtering (we've defined)
            CreateUpdateBookDto> 
    {

    }
```

> Notice, we've changed `PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto` to `MySearchFilterDto`.

BookAppService.cs

```cs
public class BookAppService :
        CrudAppService<
            Book, 
            BookDto,
            Guid, 
            MySearchFilterDto, //Used for paging/sorting + filtering (we've defined)
            CreateUpdateBookDto>, 
        IBookAppService 
    {
        public BookAppService(IRepository<Book, Guid> repository)
            : base(repository)
        {

        }

        //override the GetList method to enable searching (in here I only search by book name, you can also search by other props)
        public override async Task<PagedResultDto<BookDto>> GetListAsync(MySearchFilterDto input)
        {
            var queryable = await base.Repository.GetQueryableAsync();
            var query = queryable.WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.Filter), book => book.Name.ToLower()
                .Contains(input.Filter.ToLower()))
                .OrderBy(input.Sorting ?? nameof(Book.Name).ToLower())
                .PageBy(input);


            var count = await AsyncExecuter.CountAsync(query);
            var books = await AsyncExecuter.ToListAsync(query);

            var result = ObjectMapper.Map<List<Book>, List<BookDto>>(books);

            return new PagedResultDto<BookDto> { Items = result, TotalCount = count };
        }
    }
```

- Open your `Index.cshtml` (under Pages -> Books) and add the search input.

Index.cshtml

```
//...

<abp-card>
    <abp-card-header>
        <h2>@L["Books"]</h2>
    </abp-card-header>
    <abp-card-body>
        <abp-column size="_3">
           Search: 
            <input name="Search" /> @* add search input *@
        </abp-column>
        <abp-table striped-rows="true" id="BooksTable"></abp-table>
    </abp-card-body>
</abp-card>
```

- Open your `Index.js` (under Pages -> Books) and get the value of the search input and pass it to the GetList method.

Index.js

```js
$(function () {

   //get the value of the search input
    var getFilter = function () {
        return {
            filter: $("input[name='Search']").val(),
        };
    };

    var dataTable = $('#BooksTable').DataTable(
        abp.libs.datatables.normalizeConfiguration({
            serverSide: true,
            paging: true,
            order: [[1, "asc"]],
            searching: false,
            scrollX: true,
            ajax: abp.libs.datatables.createAjax(myDemoTest4421.books.book.getList, getFilter), //pass the filter to the GetList method
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    title: 'Name',
                    data: "name"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Type',
                    data: "type",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'PublishDate',
                    data: "publishDate",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return luxon
                            .DateTime
                            .fromISO(data, {
                                locale: abp.localization.currentCulture.name
                            }).toLocaleString();
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Price',
                    data: "price"
                },
                {
                    title: 'CreationTime', data: "creationTime",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return luxon
                            .DateTime
                            .fromISO(data, {
                                locale: abp.localization.currentCulture.name
                            }).toLocaleString(luxon.DateTime.DATETIME_SHORT);
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
    );
   
   //when search input changed (a new character typed) reload the datatable
   $("input[name='Search'").change(function () {
        dataTable.ajax.reload();
    });
});
```

---

After following these steps, you should be able to search your books by name.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer!
This is exactly what I've been hoping for.
I'll try it asap.
Regards, Tom

Comment: It works great. Thanks again!
I just use "keyup" instead of "change".

Comment: There are 2 issues with this solution:  1.) The paging does not work anymore.
2.) Sorting by clicking on the column headers doesn't work.
Can you please help on fixing these?
@engincan-veske

Comment: @Metal-Frog, I've updated the question. You can use the `OrderBy` and `PageBy` methods to provide sorting and paging.

Comment: I've added  `var query = queryable.WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.Filter), book => book.Name.ToLower()
                    .Contains(input.Filter.ToLower()))
                .OrderBy(input.Sorting ?? nameof(Book.Name).ToLower())
                .PageBy(input);`  but paging still doesn't work.

Comment: Any further ideas?

Comment: Those who want to just enable searching and sorting from current table needs to set serverSide: false

Comment: great many thanks for this .. however the typo at the end of book input field selector prevented this from running. Fixed with this :    
         filter: $("input[name='Search']").val(),